# What is the most simple way to implement a newsletter?

Tags: email, email-server, newsletters

We have a quarterly newsletter, and a list of subscriptions in a csv file(this can change if necessary).

The previous method was to use a python script that generates the newsletter from a content source and sends the mail to the recipients one by one using smtplib.

Now we changed the way we write newsletters and we need some daemon to send and e-mail and will forward the email one by one for each recipient. What is the easiest way of doing this? Our manager uses MS Exchange to prepare the letter and we have a Linux server that we can configure however we want.

I heard EXIM can be configured in such a way.

Answer (score 3):

*Easiest* way is probably to buy in a service like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).  There are a lot of advantages to this - particularly that those companies care to spend the time to get your newsletter through spam filters etc, saving you the hassle.

Next simplest is setting up a mailing list server such as [Mailman](http://www.list.org/).  This will get you double opt in, list management, and sends to recipients one by one, as you request.

If you don't already have EXIM or Postfix on your Linux server, you aren't going to find a super simple way of doing this, unless you already understand MTAs in general, and a specific one in detail.